# My pink lemon tree isn't blooming

Tags: trees, lemons

My pink lemon tree isn't blooming. I bought it a month ago and it came in a small container. I replanted it into a bigger container and still nothing is happening.

Comment: Can you add a photo of the plant...and a few details like your watering schedule, drainage, sunlight, which part of the world this is etc...

Comment: Are you sure it's supposed to bloom the first year after the transplant? How old was it when you got it?